# What is the simplest way to sort the array of object?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to sort an array like this

```js
[
    {
        'type': 'apple', 
        'like': 3
    }, 
    {
        'type': 'pear', 
        'like': 5
    }, 
    ...
]
```

I was using `lodash` lib for the sorting.
Is there a any more simple way to sort an array by `like` value?

Comment: Check Array.sort()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about pure JS `sort` method:

```js
var k=[{'type': 'apple', 'like': 7}, {'type': 'pear', 'like': 5},{'type': 'pear', 'like': 10}];

console.log(k.sort((a,b)=>a.like-b.like));
```

If you want to understand it better, read it [here](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array/sort).

I hope this helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can directly do this in javascript in the following manner:

```js
var my_arr = [{'type': 'apple', 'like': 3}, {'type': 'pear', 'like': 5}, {'type': 'pea', 'like': 7}, {'type': 'orange', 'like': 1}, {'type': 'grape', 'like': 4}] 

console.log(my_arr)

my_arr.sort((a, b) => (a.like > b.like) ? 1 : -1)

console.log(my_arr)
```

where my_arr is the original array you were attempting to sort